# Last byte missing when casting from varbinary to varchar

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I got the last byte losing when converting varbinary to varchar in some case. For example:

```
DECLARE @binary varbinary(8000),
        @char varchar(8000)
set @binary = 0x000082
set @char = CAST(@binary as varchar(8000))
select BinaryLength=DATALENGTH(@binary), CharLength=DATALENGTH(@char)
```

The result is

```
BinaryLength   CharLength
    3              2
```

The affected byte value is from 0x81 - 0xFE.

The stranger thing is that if I use varchar(MAX) instead varchar(8000) when casting, there is no any problem.

Could someone tell me the root cause of the issue?

PS: I run the sql in MS SQL server 2008.

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried this on both a SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 server and get 3 for both on each one. Is this the exact code that reproduces the problem on yours?

Comment: What is the database/server collation please?

Comment: Which SQL Server edition, build number, service pack, compatibility level, and collation are using?